# What are the buffs in this vanilla wow screenshot?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What are buffs in the vanilla wow screenshot shown below?

I know two of them: the purple paw is Mark of the Wild, and the blue lightning cloud is Arcane Intellect. What are the others?

[image: buff icons]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order from left to right, top to bottom they are:

- [Greater Blessing of Salvation](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Greater_Blessing_of_Salvation), a legacy Paladin buff that reduced threat generation by 30%.
- [Divine Spirit](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Divine_Spirit), a Priest buff that (at the time) provided a flat +Spirit buff. Thanks to Mark B for providing proof.
- [Power Word: Fortitude](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Power_Word%3A_Fortitude), a Priest buff that increases Stamina. At the time, it was a flat +Stamina buff.
- [Arcane Intellect](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Arcane_Intellect), a legacy Mage spell that was a shorter, reagent-free version of Arcane Brilliance. It granted a flat +Intellect buff, but was made obsolete when the reagent cost was removed from Arcane Brilliance.
- [Fire Resistance Aura](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Fire_Resistance_Aura), a Paladin aura that increases Fire Resistance.
- [Aspect of the Hawk](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Aspect_of_the_Hawk), a legacy Hunter aura that increased Attack Power by a flat amount.
- [Resist Fire](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=15123/resist-fire), a buff you got by using Mind Control on the [Scarshield Spellbinder](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=9098/scarshield-spellbinder#abilities) mobs in LBRS/UBRS. Many Raids used this for Molten Core and Blackwing Lair.
- [Gift of the Wild](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Gift_of_the_Wild), the group version of Mark of the Wild.
- [Greater Blessing of Wisdom](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Greater_Blessing_of_Wisdom), a Paladin buff that increases mana regeneration by a fixed amount per 5 seconds.
- [Greater Blessing of Kings](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Greater_Blessing_of_Kings), a legacy Paladin buff that increased all stats.
- [Greater Blessing of Light](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Greater_Blessing_of_Light), a legacy Paladin buff that increased the effect of any Paladin's Holy Light and Flash of Light healing spells.

Comment: The red shield looks like something a Fire Resistance Potion of some sort would give you. I'm not sure what the first unknown one is, but I really feel like I should know it! (source: I played on a private vanilla server 2 years ago)

Comment: @Pyritie Most potion buffs used the icon of the potion themselves (or at least they did back then). I'm pretty sure the first one is a Paladin or Priest buff, I just can't put my finger on it at the moment. The rest is pretty much from memory, but classic was a looong time ago now and I stopped playing just prior to WoD.

Comment: I remember making a ton of those fire protection potions and that was definitely the icon they used. Vanilla wasn't very consistent with icons. Here's the buff they gave: https://www.wow-one.com/database/index.php?spell=17543

Comment: @Pyritie I seem to recall the elemental protection potions weren't actually *resistance* potions as such, they just gave a one or two minute shield that blocked the next X damage from that school

Comment: yeah, but they were still useful in molten core and blackwing lair :)

Comment: @Pyritie Oh absolutely - but that second unknown buff can't be one of them because the duration is too long...

Comment: Oh right, that's a good point.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Did the DS icon change at some point? The only icon I remember ever seeing for it was [this one](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/File:Spell_holy_divinespirit.png), with the group version having three people on it instead of one.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I think originally DS used to be something you had to spec for, so *maybe* when it was a talent it had that icon, and that when they made it a core spell they changed the icon at the same time?

Comment: That's Gift of the Wild, not Mark of the Wild.  You can tell by the duration (Mark of the Wild only lasts 30 minutes and was cast on a single person).

Comment: @Powerlord Except [this](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/File:Spell_nature_giftofthewild.png) is the GotW icon. I know there used to be some scrolls for buff spells, so I wonder if it was cast from one of those instead

Comment: @JonK That's the SPELL icon, the effect icon is just the Mark of the Wild icon.  Same with Power Word: Fortitude and Prayer of Fortitude both using the Power Word: Fortitude icon for its effect.

Comment: @Powerlord No, back then PoF, PoS, GotW, AB and all of the Paladin blessings used the same icon as the group buff spell IIRC. It always used to set off my OCD when I had the single target buff icon instead of the group one...

Comment: @JonK And yet, in Classic, Mark of the Wild only lasted 30 minutes not the 45+ shown.  That's besides the whole having to cast the spell 40 times to cover the entire raid bit.

Comment: @Powerlord Which is why I now think it's the version cast from a scroll, which I believe lasted for an hour. Although I'm struggling to find any references to such a scroll, so perhaps I'm misremembering it. Either way, it makes little real difference which version it is, they had the same effect.

Comment: I thought it was Divine Spirit as well, but was more familiar with the WotLK version.  [This page suggests](http://db.vanillagaming.org/?spell=16875) the icon may have indeed changed over time.  99% sure it was a priest buff at any rate.

Comment: I believe the last icon (second from the left) is the priest spell Inner Fire.

Comment: @twobugs I'm not sure it is - the Inner Fire icon that I remember is sort of like [a ring with fire coming off the top](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/File:Spell_holy_innerfire.png). I do agree that it's a Priest spell however.

Comment: http://smg.photobucket.com/user/SirAlex1337/media/WoW/ShowingmyUI.jpg.html The second (unknown) one is divine spirit.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for that screenshot, I've updated the answer with DS now